# Sitecore Glass Mapper ObjectToSwitchTo null reference in page editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I have the following structure as Template in visual studio :

Under a page, i have one or more link root

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{4AAA9A10-36C2-484F-A648-2BEF349F0052}", AutoMap = true)]
public class LinkRoot : IBaseTemplate
{
    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<LinkItem> Children { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateId)]
    public virtual Guid TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public ItemUri Uri { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; private set; }


}
```

Under the link root i've LinkItems

```
[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
public class LinkItem : IBaseTemplate
{
    [SitecoreField("Link Name")]
    public virtual string LinkName { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("Link")]
    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public ItemUri Uri { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; private set; }
}
```

I display those items in a view like that :

```
 @foreach (var link in Model.Children.Where(o => o.TemplateId.Equals(TemplateIDs.LinksRoot.Guid)))
    {
        foreach (var linkChildren in link.Children)
        {
            using (BeginRenderLink(linkChildren, x => x.Link, isEditable: true))
            {
        @Editable(linkChildren, x => x.LinkName)
            }
        }
    }
```

It works great, i can see my links with the good name etc, but when i go to the page editor i got this error :

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectToSwitchTo
>
> at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
>     at Sitecore.Common.Switcher`2.Enter(TValue objectToSwitchTo)
>     at Sitecore.Data.Items.ContextItemSwitcher..ctor(Item item)
>     at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression`1 field, Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context context, Database database, TextWriter writer)

Does someone already experienced that or have an idea why i have this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that Glass can't resolve the template of the LinkItem model.
Instead of:

```
[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
public class LinkItem : IBaseTemplate
```

Try to explicitly define the template ID:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{your-template-guid}", AutoMap = true)]
public class LinkItem : IBaseTemplate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug, can you log it on github as an issue.

Comment: Yeah sure i'll do that

Comment: Was a bug request created for this issue?  I'm having the same problem now, and I haven't found a resolution

Comment: I don't think we had a bug report in the end

Comment: I notice that the above class does not have virtual properties for Id, Language, etc. You MUST use virtual properties with Glas.Mapper.