# Glass Mapper errors in Page Editor mode when using @RenderLink or @Render when you view / partial takes an IEnum and you iterate over it

Tags: sitecore, aero-glass, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

We are using GlassMapper.  We are passing an Ienum of a GlassType generated by TFS To a partial view from a controller.  In the controller we are iterating over our Ienum and then using @RenderLink or @Render syntax.  When you view the page its fine.  However if you try to use page editor you get the following error

VALUE CANNOT BE NULL. PARAMETER NAME: OBJECTTOSWITCHTO

AT SITECORE.DIAGNOSTICS.ASSERT.ARGUMENTNOTNULL(OBJECT ARGUMENT, STRING ARGUMENTNAME)
   AT SITECORE.COMMON.SWITCHER`2.ENTER(TVALUE OBJECTTOSWITCHTO)
   AT SITECORE.COMMON.SWITCHER`2..CTOR(TVALUE OBJECTTOSWITCHTO)
   AT SITECORE.DATA.ITEMS.CONTEXTITEMSWITCHER..CTOR(ITEM ITEM)
   AT GLASS.MAPPER.SC.GLASSHTML.MAKEEDITABLE[T](EXPRESSION`1 FIELD, EXPRESSION`1 STANDARDOUTPUT, T MODEL, OBJECT PARAMETERS, CONTEXT CONTEXT, DATABASE DATABASE, TEXTWRITER WRITER)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380363/1218297) in Glass Mapper, Try updating Glass Mapper to latest version and see if that fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  We are using the latest version :(

Answer (score 0):

I would check security. Maybe the editor doesn't have access to the item that is being switched to.

Comment: Ok I will check,  maybe its something like that.  Should the page error like that though?

Comment: I am running as admin and i get the same error.  We currently dont have an permissions set

Comment: Sure, I will do it tomorrow morning. :)

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply.  It looks like with have got around the issue.  It seems that if we get TreeList from Solr by GUID then GlassMapper cannot map.  It could be our config.  We will do some more investigation